# Custom pivot rows to average pivot data within pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have temperature data in five-minute intervals across a number of years.

My objective is to pull together daytime (07:00-21:00) and nighttime (22:00-06:00) average for each month to be aggregated in a separate sheet.

I can use a pivot to find hourly averages across each month, can I modify the rows to group to daytime and nighttime?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, but depends on what your data looks like.

I just use `=IF(AND(D2>TIME(7,0,0),D2<TIME(21,0,0)),"day","night")`

[image: data]

Then your pivot can look like this - if you make sure your data is in tabular format

[image: Pivot]

Comment: Edited to provide an answer specific to your question

Comment: Great idea using an additional column to filter, am currently running into issues with the formula having copied my DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM data into a column formatted as HH:MM:SS, but will update as soon as I've cracked it. Thanks again!

Comment: Format cells > More Number Formats > Special: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: So, just focused on the column with HH:MM:SS (A2), the following formula classes everything as NIGHT : =IF(AND(A2>TIME(7,0,0),A2<TIME(21,0,0)),"DAY","NIGHT")

Comment: I was able to find the method that worked for me in another forum, (Thanks PauleyB!) but the formula that works for me is: =IF(AND(OR(AND(HOUR(A43)>=22,HOUR(A43)<=23),AND(HOUR(A43)>=0,HOUR(A43)<=6)),OR(AND(HOUR(A43)>=22,HOUR(A43)<=23),AND(HOUR(A43)>=0,HOUR(A43)<=6))),"Night","Day")